# Переадресация с поддомена на домен

Tags: javascript, html, href, location

Подскажите, как лучше реализовать такую затею. Я создаю поддомены своего домена, чтобы когда заходят на определенный (их будет несколько) поддомен, скрипт перекидывал на основной мой домен, НО заменял текст `(innerHTML)` и `value` в `input type="hidden"`вписывал `url`.

Допустим есть домен - domen.ru. Я создаю поддомен - d.domen.ru. На основном домене (domen.ru) написан номер один, пусть будет 8(812)123-4567. Я хочу чтобы, когда заходят на поддомен d.domen.ru скрипт перекидывал на основной домен и заменял на основном домене некую информацию. Вот пример:

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden">
</form>

document.querySelector('input').value = window.local.href;

<div>
  <a href="tel:123">123</a>
</div>

document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = <a href="tel:098">098</a>;
```

Потом, если заходят уже на другой поддомен, допустим f.domen.ru, происходит все тоже самое, только заменяется на другой номер. only js please!

Как мне расположить файл со скриптом, что бы при открытии поддомена он срабатывал, перебрасывал на (!)домен и на домене заменял номер, который указан в скрипте. (каждый такой скрипт, но с разным номером будет лежать на поддомене. Всего таких скриптов и поддоменов будет около 4-5)

Answer (score 1):

Скажу сразу, такое легче реализовать через PHP, но если вам уж так важно чтобы это было на JavaScript, вы бы могли использовать LocalStorage, куда вы можете записать нужную вам информацию, а затем её считывать на другом сайте.

`localStorage.setItem('название', 'литерал');` - записать значение

`localStorage.getItem('название');` - получить значение

Comment: php не знаю. Интересная идея. Т.е если я добавлю файл со скриптом на поддомен, он прочтется и перекинет на домен? а как на php получилось бы?

Comment: Можно сделать через `header("Location: link")` это пересылка, а запоминать информацию можно через cookie.